# Unable to retrieve fields when using REST API only

Tags: soql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT ProductCode FROM OpportunityLineItem limit 500
```

When I run it on `Workbench.developerforce.com`'s SOQL Query I get a result.

But then, when I run it using `RESTful API` I get the following error:

```
[
    {
        "message": "\nSELECT ProductCode FROM OpportunityLineItem\n       ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:8\nNo such column 'ProductCode' on entity 'OpportunityLineItem'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.",
        "errorCode": "INVALID_FIELD"
    }
]
```

The description for `ProductCode` is as follows:

```
aggregatable: true
autoNumber: false
byteLength: 765
calculated: false
caseSensitive: false
createable: false
custom: false
defaultedOnCreate: false
deprecatedAndHidden: false
digits: 0
filterable: true
groupable: true
idLookup: false
label: Product Code
length: 255
name: ProductCode
nameField: false
namePointing: false
nillable: true
permissionable: true
polymorphicForeignKey: false
precision: 0
queryByDistance: false
restrictedPicklist: false
scale: 0
searchPrefilterable: false
soapType: xsd:string
sortable: true
type: string
unique: false
updateable: false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using `/services/data/v20.0/query/?q=` as the REST end-point. I changed it to **v40.0** and now it's working.

Comment: Yes, ProductCode was added to OpportunityLineItem sometime after V30